# Mod_rewrite redirect POST params

Tags: apache, redirect, mod-rewrite

Hi am trying to redirect from http to https and maintain POST params.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
#   RewriteEngine On
#   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
#   RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}:443%{REQUEST_URI}

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^/?myapp/(.*) https://gladwww01uat.uk:443/myapp/start.do
</IfModule>
```

Both of these rules redirect the request but as a GET request. How can I maintain the POST params?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No that's not possible. With external redirects POST data is not transferred (because of security concerns in doing so).